# React update component after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function to get the width of the container. This function gets called every time, when the window changes the size. In this function I set the state "containerWidth" to the current width of the container. 
I need the width, for the function getNumberOfItems which calculates how many items fit into the container. But when I change the window size and set the state "containerWidth" the function "getNumberofItems" doesn't update. How can I achieve that the function "getNumberOfItems" gets called every time when the window size changes (with the new state containerWidth)?

Thanks for your help

```
  getContainerWidth() {
    let width = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].offsetWidth + 'px';
    this.setState({
      containerWidth: width,
    });
  }

getNumberOfItems(){
  let width = this.state.containerWidth;
  let postWidth = this.state.postWidth;
  ...
  ...
  ...
  return numberOfItems;
}

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.getContainerWidth.bind(this));
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getContainerWidth.bind(this);
    this.getNumberOfItems();
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.getNumberOfItems.bind(this));
  }
```

Comment: from where is the getNumberOfItems invoked

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `componentWillMount` is only called one before the components mounts, the `getNumberOfItems` function is not being called on `containerWidth` change, what you can do is call it from the `componentDidUpdate` function like

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(this.state.containerWidth !== prevState.containerWidth) { 
        this.getNumberOfItems();
    }
}
getNumberOfItems(){
  let width = this.state.containerWidth;
  let postWidth = this.state.postWidth;
  ...
  ...
  ...
  return numberOfItems;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

setState method takes a callback method as the second argument. So you could do:

```
getContainerWidth() {
let width = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].offsetWidth + 'px';
this.setState({
  containerWidth: width,
},this.getNumberOfItems);
```

}